# If an object is enclosed within a metallic spherical shell having surface charge + q C. The object will carry charge - q C.?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I have doubt in the statement is there any link between surface charge and object enclosed within the shell.
I think object in  enclosed shell can have any charge +ve or -ve .
Or it is due to the fact that if +ve charge is distributed over the sphere then electric field inside the shell is zero

Comment: is the object inside initially uncharged? is it made up  of nonconducting material?

Comment: suppose we don't know its initial state.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have some object inside the spherical metal shell and the charge on that object is $+q$. We won't worry for the moment how the charge got there:

[image: Shell]

The metal shell is a conductor, and that means the field inside it is zero. So if we draw a Gaussian surface inside the shell, shown by the dashed circle, then because the field everywhere on the surface is zero the total charge inside the surface must be zero. That means the inner surface of our spherical shell must carry a charge $-q$ that is equal and opposite to the charge on the object inside it.

The total charge on the spherical shell can be anything because we can put as much or as little charge on it as we want. Suppose the total charge on the spherical shell is $Q$, then the charge will distribute itself between the inner and outer surfaces. That means the charge on the outer surface will be $Q+q$ so that when we add up the charges on the inner and outer surfaces the result comes to $Q$.

There isn't any link between the total charge on the shell and on the object we put inside it, since we can makes those charges $q$ and $Q$ anything we want. However there is a link between the charge on the **inner surface** of the shell. That always has to be equal and opposite to the charge inside it, and the charge on the outer surface of the shell will adjust to achieve this.

Comment: Where do you get these funny cartoon scientists (in your diagram) from? :-)